# Aller "interessierter" oder "interessierten" Menschen?

Tags: adjective, genitive, adjective-ending

Wie wird "interessiert" im Genitiv Plural gebeugt, wenn kein Artikel vorhanden ist?

Beispiel:

> Diese Frage wurde im Sinne aller an Sport interessierter Menschen beantwortet.

Ich stolpere bei jedem Lesen über die Endung "er" des Wortes "interessierter". Für mich klingt "interessierten" an dieser Stelle flüssiger. Aber ich bin mir sehr unsicher, was richtig ist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Genitiv Plural vom Adjektiv *interessiert* ist

> interessierter

Diese Form nennt man *starke Deklination*.

Im Deutschen werden Adjektive allerdings anders (*"schwach"*) dekliniert, wenn sie mit Artikel oder - wie im Beispiel - mit einem Pronomen oder einem Artikel verwendet werden, zum Beispiel

> Die Bärte **alter** Männer.

aber

> Die Bärte der **alten** Männer.
>   Die Bärte aller **alten** Männer.

Also gilt in diesem Falle:

> Diese Frage wurde im Sinne aller an Deutsch interessierten Menschen beantwortet.

;-)

Comment: Oh, ich hätte jetzt genau das Gegenteil erwartet, weil der Artikel fehlt. Zählt "aller" also als Artikel in diesem Zusammenhang?

Comment: @Martin ja, bei Pronomen oder Zahlwörtern wie "alle" wird auch schwach dekliniert.

Answer (score 4):

Die vortreffliche Erklärung splattnes trifft auch für andere Pronomina zu:

> Die Bärte beider alten Männer
>   Die Bärte solcher alten Männer
>   Die Bärte welcher alten Männer?

Vorsicht aber.  Es gibt Pronomina nach denen stark dekliniert wird:

> Die Bärte einiger alter  Männer
>   Die Bärte anderer alter Männer
>   Die Bärte vieler alter Männer

Es gibt auch sympathische  Pronomina für welche der Gebrauch schwankt: da kannst du keine Fehler machen!

> Der Reiz mancher langen/langer Bärte ist unwiderstehlich

Im Zweifelfall, ein gutes Grammatikbuch nachschlagen (wie immer).

Comment: Auf Wikipedia gibt es dazu auch noch einige Tips und Regeln: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Adjektive.2C_Pronomen_und_Artikel