# ...nach deren intraläsionaler/intraläsionalen Applikation

Tags: adjective, grammatical-case, declension

Wie und warum muss bei folgendem Satz die Endung des Adjektivs intraläsional**er** oder intraläsional**en** sein?

> Untersuchungen zu Medikamenten nach deren intraläsional(en/er) Applikation.

Comment: Related: [Aller “interessierter” oder “interessierten” Menschen?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1925/9551)

Comment: @Loong Ich habe mir den Beitrag nun mehrmals durchgelesen. Um es auf mein Beispiel umzumünzen sagt man also "Medikamente intraläsionaler Applikation", wenn man von Mitteln spricht, die intraläsional appliziert werden, aber "Medikamente der intraläsional**en** Applikation". Wenn mich meine eingerosteten Deutschregeln nicht ganz im Stich lassen, dann ist doch "deren" ein Possesivpronomen, ja? Laut des Artikels müsste dann doch aber schwach dekliniert werden und es müsste "...nach deren intraläsional**en** Applikation" heißen. Das würde aber im Gegensatz zum Kommentar von Kilian stehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richtig ist

> Untersuchungen zu Medikamenten nach deren intraläsional**er** Applikation

Eine Begründung findest Du z.B. bei [Deutsche Grammatik 2.0](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/relativsatz/possessive-relativsaetze/) oder (ich empfehle es immer wieder gern) bei canoo.net im Blog von [Dr. Bopp](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2016/01/26/dessen-deren-und-deren-nachfolgende-nachbarn/) und auf der [Seite zu den Relativpronomen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/RelPron-der-die-das.html#Anchor-Attributiver-49575).

Es handelt sich bei *deren* um die Genitivform des Relativpronomens *die*, und diese Form (ebenso wie *dessen*), kann **attributiv** gebraucht werden. Das Pronomen steht dann also *wie ein Adjektiv* vor dem Nomen. Es bestimmt dann natürlich nicht den Kasus des Nomens, gleicht sich ihm aber auch nicht an (es ist ja schon eine Genitivform, die "so wie sie ist" zum Attribut wird). Man sieht das recht gut in einem der Beispiele von canoo.net:

> die Dame, deren roter Sportwagen vor dem Haus steht

Bei *roter Sportwagen* handelt es sich eindeutig um einen Nominativ, und das Beispiel lässt sich gut auf die drei anderen Fälle übertragen:

> die Dame, deren roten Sportwagens sich neulich ein Dieb bemächtigte
> die Dame, deren rotem Sportwagen gestern der Sprit ausgegangen ist
> die Dame, deren roten Sportwagen ich gerne einmal fahren würde

Und auch wenn, wie in Deiner Frage, vor dem Einleitewort des Relativsatzes eine Präposition steht, bleibt das so. Die Präposition bestimmt die Flexion von Adjektiv und Nomen. Das Relativpronomen reiht sich wie ein Attribut ein (wird aber, wie gesagt, selbst nicht noch einmal dekliniert).

> die Dame, dank deren roten Sportwagens ich es gestern noch rechtzeitig zum Zug geschafft habe
> die Dame, mit deren rotem Sportwagen ich schon einmal fahren durfte
> die Dame, für deren roten Sportwagen ich jeden Preis bezahlen würde

In all diesen Fällen gilt:

> Adjektive werden nach *deren* und *dessen* stark flektiert.

Das hat sogar eine gewisse innere Logik, denn wie canoo.net im [Artikel zur starken Flexion](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Stark.html) ausführt:

> Adjektive ... werden dann stark flektiert, wenn Genus, Kasus und Numerus nicht schon durch einen Artikelwort angegeben werden.

Aus dem immer gleichen *deren* lässt sich eben nicht *Genus, Kasus und Numerus* von *rot* in den obigen Beispielen herleiten.

(Hilfreich auch diese [Übersicht, welche Artikelwörter welche Flexion verlangen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Artikelwort.html).)

Zurück zu Deiner Frage: Die Präposition *nach* verlangt den Dativ, gesucht ist also die starke Flexion von *intraläsionale Applikation* im Dativ, und diese lautet eben *intraläsionaler Applikation*.

Comment: Also ist hier "deren" kein Possesivpronomen wie ich oben fälschlich vermutet habe, obwohl es ein Besitzverhältnis anzeigt. Vielen Dank für diese einfache Erklärung.

Comment: @halirutan Bitteschön! Wenn _ihrer_ statt _deren_ dastehen würde, hätten wir es mit einem Possessivpronomen zu tun.

Comment: Die Regel stimmt, aber ein 'richtiges Pronomen' ist das nicht. Allerdings wird in vielen Grammatiken wird zwischen echt pronominalem und nomenbegleitendem Gebrauch bei den sog. Pronomen nicht unterschieden. Dessen, deren (und derer)_ sind zuweilen mit Possessivartikeln austauschbar und haben eine ähnliche Funktion, nur sind sie zusätzlich relativ. Satzfunktional handelt es sich um possessive Relativartikel. Weil sie indeklinabel sind, wird wie bei anderen invariablen Artikelwörtern das nachfolgende Adjektiv 'stark' flektiert, bzw.: Es trägt die Genus-, Kasus- und Numerusendungen.